# Delphi method call followed by ()

Tags: delphi, function-pointers, delphi-xe2

I've encountered in some code the following call :

`SQLParser.Parse(qry.SQL.Text)().GetWhereClause`

and I don't understand the meaning of those 2 parenthesis after the Parse call. Following the implementation I got the declarations for each one of them:

```
 TSQLParser = class
  public
    class function Parse(const ASQL: string): ISmartPointer<TSQLStatement>;

  TSQLStatement = class
    function GetWhereClause: string;
```

and

```
  ISmartPointer<T> = reference to function: T;
```

Comment: The fact that Delphi allows function calls without parens (for functions with no arguments) is, in my view, a great weakness. This convenience feature leads to ambiguity. Not only ambiguity to the reader of the code, but also to the compiler. When the compiler has an expression of procedural type how does it know whether or not you mean to refer to that procedural value, or to invoke the procedure?

Comment: @David: you can use @ with a procedural type. This will give you the procedural value, and not the result of its invocation. OTOH, if you add parentheses, you get the result of the invocation. Calling a procedure without parens is a legacy from the old Pascal days, when this was not a problem yet.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I understand the history. That doesn't really help us now though. And using `@` is a very bad idea. It yields an untyped pointer to the code. No use for anon methods, no use for methods of objects. Please do not ever suggest the general use of `@` with procedural types. Its use is very very limited to special circumstances.

Comment: I disagree. You're right it's extra work for the compiler and may cause ambiguity, but considering that in almost all cases a mention of the identifier of a (argument-less) procedure/function is meant to invoke it, I find it quite suitable to a well designed language that the (ugly!) empty parentheses are optional. (And prefixing `@` is as un-ambiguous as it gets.)

Comment: @StijnSanders So you don't care about type safety? You are prepared to give that up?

Comment: I fail to see how this impacts type safety `MyFunction` is of type the result-type of the function, `@MyFunction` is of type pointer to function (with specific argument list).

Comment: @David: as Stijn says, `@MyFunc` returns a procedural type of the right type, not just an untyped pointer, just like `@MyInteger` returns a `PInteger`.

Comment: @rudy the depth of ignorance on this topic is amazing. Read this http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Expressions_(Delphi)#The_.40_Operator specifically this quote *If F is a routine (a function or procedure), @F returns F's entry point. The type of @F is always Pointer.*.

Comment: I've seen it now. So what is the problem with it? I would only use @ if there is an ambiguity between function call and function address. Then, @ works nicely; it tells the compiler you don't want to call the function.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis `var
  F: procedure(X: Integer);
  G: procedure;

begin
  F := @G;
end.
`  As I said, the depth of the ignorance of this issue is breathtaking. The needless and risky use of `@` is prevalent. You see it everywhere. It's the orthodoxy. And yet it abandons type safety. Stijn's comment gets two up votes! Why? It's factually wrong?

Comment: Yes, I know that that is possible. Just don't do it. And well, "ignorance" is such a big and often insulting word. Oh, sometimes, using @ is the only solution. Then you should use it, no matter if that is slightly less type safe.

Comment: FWIW, it is indeed used very often. But does it lead to many errors? Not AFAIK, so IME it is not such a big issue as you are trying to make it. And, as I said, "breathtaking depth of ignorance" is pretty insulting and not warranted.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You are letting your pride get in the way of your reason. Ignorance is perfectly understandable and we are all very ignorant in many different areas. Ignorance simply means the absence of knowledge. Perfectly normal and common and routine. But wilful ignorance as you are now demonstrating is not a good trait. Very very seldom is `@` needed with procedural types. Can you give me an example where it is essential to abandon type safety? Does it lead to many errors? Yes it does. It is a frequent issue here on SO. The canonical example is its use on local procedures.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  I think not-so-expert users like me would feel more comfortable with your aversion to the @ operator if we had a clearer idea of how you would propose to avoid using it.

Comment: Saying someone is ignorant in a certain field is fine, but exaggerating it with "breathtaking depth of ignorance" is not, IMO, especially since it is not warranted for anyone here. I am not demonstratung wilful ignorance, nor is anyone else either. I already said you were right, but that it is apparently not such a big issue. So maybe your pride is getting in the way.

Comment: You abandon type safety every time you cast. You abandon type safety if there is no alternative. Many languages do not offer any (compile time) type safety at all. They still get along very well. As I said, it is not such an issue, and I haven't seen many errors with it either, not even here on SO.

Comment: @MartynA Well, just don't use it! You don't need to use it. Its use has entered the lore for reasons that are now forgotten. Probably the only time that you need to use it are with badly declared function prototypes. Such as the appalling ones in Emba's header translations that they refuse to fix. There they declare callback function args as `Pointer` which forces the use of `@`. If they would only do the decent thing and use procedural types then we could have type safety. Until then it is better to use your own header translations for such functions.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis As I said, I see issues repeatedly regularly. Are you suggesting that I am making that up? Don't fall into the trap of thinking that if you have never encountered something then it does not exist.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes, abandon type safety when there is no alternative. But there is an alternative. So to choose to give up type safety when you don't need to is stupid. Don't be stupid.

Comment: @MartynA In fact, just trying to write up an example of that in more detail led me to a (benign) bug in my own code relating to this issue! I had this code:

`uses
  Windows;

function EnumWindowsProc(const hwnd: HWND; const lParam: LPARAM): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  // body of callback function removed for brevity
  Result := True;
end;

procedure CallEnumWindows;
begin
  EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);
end;`

This code does not compile because Windows.pas declares the first arg of `EnumWindows` as `Pointer`. So we need to write: `EnumWindows(@EnumWindowsProc, 0);`

Comment: @MartynA 

The correct way to translate the API is as so:

`type
  WNDENUMPROC = function(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL stdcall;

function EnumWindows(lpEnumFunc: WNDENUMPROC; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall; external user32;`

`function EnumWindowsProc(const hwnd: HWND; const lParam: LPARAM): Boolean; stdcall;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

procedure CallEnumWindows;
begin
  EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);
end;`

has three errors. The two args are const when they should not be, and the return value is `Boolean` rather than `BOOL`. All benign as it happens.

Comment: @MartynA The function should however be:

`function EnumWindowsProc(hwnd: HWND; lParam: LPARAM): BOOL; stdcall;
begin
  Result := True;
end;`

Comment: Ok, assume I'm stupid. What is the alternative?

Comment: @rudy Let's have a concrete example where you feel @ is necessary

Comment: I'll have to look for one. It doesn't happen very often.

Comment: (Oops what have I started!) I did not know referencing fn/proc always is plain pointer. I was ignorant (sorry it took your breath there for a while @DavidHeffernan). I was confused with [strato](https://github.com/stijnsanders/strato#strato) where I do have the luxury to have `@` result in a specific pointer to the specific 'call signature'.  @RudyVelthuis says "You abandon type safety every time you cast." above. I've solved that in strato by only allowing a 'dirty' cast to the left-side of an assignment (and even then only with matching memory size).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The Parse function returns a reference to a function. You can call this function. A longer equivalent form would be:

```
var
  FunctionReference: ISmartPointer<TSQLStatement>;
  SQLStatement: TSQLStatement;
begin
  { Parse returns a reference to a function. Store that function reference in FunctionReference }
  FunctionReference := TSQLParser.Parse(qry.SQL.Text);
  { The referenced function returns an object. Store that object in SQLStatement }
  SQLStatement := FunctionReference();
  { Call the GetWhereClause method on the stored object }
  SQLStatement.GetWhereClause();
```

The line in the question is just a shorter version that does not use explicit variables to store the intermediate results.